# php-fpm not creating /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock (ubuntu 18.04 server)

Tags: server, php, nginx, php-fpm

error log `ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock': No such file or directory`

Could someone help me find the problem with this as I run out of ideas below is what have looked for and from what I can see everything is fine.

files locations plus code:

**/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2 (exist)**

**/etc/init/php7.2-fpm.conf (exist, see below code)**

```
# php7.2-fpm - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager

description "The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager"
author "Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

# you can uncomment this with recent upstart
# reload signal USR2

pre-start script
mkdir -p /run/php
chmod 0755 /run/php
chown www-data:www-data /run/php
end script

respawn
exec /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf
```

**/etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm (exist, see code below only copied what i think is necessary)**

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php-fpm7.2
CONFFILE=/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config $CONFFILE"
CONF_PIDFILE=$(sed -n 's/^pid[ =]*//p' $CONFFILE)   
PIDFILE=${CONF_PIDFILE:-/run/php/php7.2-fpm.pid}
TIMEOUT=30
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

**/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php7.2-fpm (exist, see code below)**

```
 pid = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.pid
```

**/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf (exist, see code below)**

```
 user = www-data
 group = www-data
 listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
 listen.owner = www-data
 listen.group = www-data
 ;listen.mode = 0660 (i have comment this on and off, no changes on the above error output)
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default (exist, see code below**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; (I have changed this to /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock but no difference /var/run is a symlink to /run
}
```

I dont know where else to look for the error or how to fix it.

could someone help me share some light on where the error could be? thanks

Comment: Do You have `/run/php/` folder created with permissions to write ? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859131/unable-to-bind-listening-socket-for-address-php-fpm

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I created the folder and change permission to ```www-data```, once i restart php7.2-fpm then it works, but once the server is reboot, the folder gets removed and php7.2-fpm crashes

Comment: You can use `systemd` to create this folder on each reboot as they are temporary : https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot - see if You have this file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php7.2-fpm.conf` ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz thanks mate, i was thinking of systemd to create the folder, but i ended up re-installing ubuntu as I had some other issues as well. its all fixed now, but thanks for the links i will bookmarks those and keep in mind in the future :)